# Eclipse, Tomcat, Jersey /JAXB: Hot redeployment problems

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jersey

I'm using a setup specified in the title. Nothing unusual.

Many times (almost always), after saving a file (HTML or JS! Not even Java!), and re-loading the webpage hosted on this Tomcat (which uses Jersey & Jaxb etc), I get a bunch of:

```
Apr 10, 2014 12:52:23 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: ... loader/META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext     (No such file or directory)]
    at      com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)
```

What have I done to deserve this?  :-)

The implication is that I have to stop, and re-start Tomcat every time, and that wastes a lot of time.

PS
'Automatic publish after build event' = true
module--> auto reload = false

I spent hours trying to solve this, googling the hell out of these terms, and getting back a lot of irrelevant stuff.

Thank you!